# Pushing master branch to different instance of app

Tags: heroku, push, staging

Let's say I have two versions of my app on heroku named 'my_app' and 'my_app_staging'. How do I push just to the staging version of my app?

When I use:

```
git push heroku master
```

It pushes to just 'my_app' which is what I want.

But I tried to set up another remote named 'staging' to 'my_app_staging' and when I used:

```
git push staging master
```

It pushed the master branch to both instances of the app instead of just the staging instance.

Comment: What does `git remote -v` say?

Comment: I solved this through another means, so I'm not sure what it said when it didn't work.

Comment: What did you do? You might want to update the original question to possibly help others in the future :)

Comment: I added the answer from my notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution that seems to work well. Instead of trying to push the master to the staging instance on heroku, I am now working on a branch and pushing the branch.

Here is what I did to an existing production app, to add a staging app and push to it separately:

**Forking An Existing App**

First fork the app and duplicate the current database and environment variables:

```
heroku fork -a app_production app_staging
```

**Add Remote**

Add new remote so you have something to push to from your local git:

```
git remote add staging git@heroku.com:app_staging.git
```

**Update Staging**

Make new branch.

```
git checkout -b new/branch
```

After making the changes. Commit and push the new branch to the staging version of the app

```
git add .
git commit
git push staging new/branch:master
```

**Update Master**

This only updates the staging app. Once you are satisfied that the staging instance is working. Merge the branch into the master and use this to push it to the production app:

```
git push heroku master
```